# Will using SMTP without encryption reduce my email deliverability?

Tags: ssl, smtp

Will using SMTP without encryption mechanisms like TLS or SSL, MIME reduce email deliverability?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, MIME is not an encryption mechanism per-se, it's just about encapsulation of 8bit thingies in a 7bit (SMTP) world.

Let's get back to TLS/SSL: Both are mechanisms to securely transfer (or deliver) an email: Transport Security. Using them (or not using them) in your email client usually doesn't reduce deliverability.

On the other hand, this MIGHT be a thing if you're talking about not-enabling TLS on your MTA (mail transport agent), so on you server's postfix/sendmail/exim/... Other MTAs might not want to talk to you if you're not supporting encryption.

In short: SMTP is evil. It's not fun. People usually pay others $$$ to have it administrated. ;-)

Comment: google/gmail will deliver the message, but throws a flag on it to let the receiving user know it wasn't sent w/ over the wire encryption.  With letsencrypt providing free certs, there isn't really a reason NOT to set up SSL/TLS

Comment: @ivanivan ahh thats nice, is there any tutorials to implement certs to smtp?

Comment: @kratos - i'm working on one for postfix+dovecot+mysql and virtual domains/users, actually use it to teach part of a course and need to copy/paste it out of the assignment and re-organize it and ....

Comment: @ivanivan it's wonderful if you post it on somewhere that would save life. :)